# Is there a Visual Studio editor feature to split a page vertically for Linq commenting?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, linq, visual-studio-2017

As time goes by my c# seems to be becoming less imperative and much more declarative. I am using LINQ , lambdas, LINQ over observables and reactive extensions.

Sometimes this can be quite hard to read, especially when concise Rx.NET linq statements embody a whole load of nuances and implementation detail in a way that is fairly opaque until studied closely.

What I would like to be able to do is divide my page of code vertically so LINQ statements and lambdas would appear on the left while comments to each line would appear on the right in neat columns. The editor as I use it now allows me to do this, but painfully, with edits losing the tabbing, or pushing comments onto the wrong line.

Is there some VS feature that allows this kind of code to be more readable and help with this kind of editing?

Comment: @mjwills Found a solution called Code Alignment as a VSIX. Works, if that helps.

Comment: Can the losers who voted to close please confess here? Before they realize the errors of their ways? And before they end their lives?

Answer (score 3):

Actually I found a VSIX called Code Alignment. This allows you to align code by "//" (no regex).The wiki is here https://github.com/cpmcgrath/codealignment/wiki/Example-1:-Align-by-equals